# jQuery .each() or other method. Which should I use for this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

We have two 360 viewers using the jQuery Reel plugin.  The two are spinning fine on the same page using classes.  We have set up zoom capabilities and rotation sliders using jQuery UI.  The issue is we can't get each of the sliders or the zoom buttons to control its parent image.  Can anyone help? Thanks, URL is http://www.dmns.org/test/jquery-360/index.html . Any help is appreciated.  Code is below.

```
 var zoomAmount = 100;
 var originalHeight = 0;
 var originalWidth = 0;
// Slide Bar for the "Zoom" control
var zoomSlider;
var totalFrames;
var isObjectRotatingViaSlider = false;
var isObjectZoomingViaSlider = false;
var maxZoomAmount = 2;
var image = $('.image');

$(document).ready(function () {
var images = $('.imageSequence').attr('value');
var imgArray = images.split(',');
totalFrames = imgArray.length;
originalHeight = $('.image').height();
originalWidth = $('.image').width();
var image = $('.image');
image.reel(
{
    brake: 1,
    frames: totalFrames,
    images: imgArray,
    //preload: totalFrames,
    cw: true,
    hint: "Click and drag",
    clickfree: false,
    preloader: 20

});

 //  var wrappingDiv = $('.example');
//$(wrappingDiv).each(function () {
    $('.ZoomIn').on('click', function (e) {
        ZoomIn();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.ZoomOut').on('click', function (e) {
        ZoomOut();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.DefaultSize').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        DefaultSize();

    });

//});//End Each


//iPad check to show or hide sliders
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
var isiPhoneOriPod = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||  (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if (!isiPad && !isAndroid && !isiPhoneOriPod) {
    // alert('not iPad');
    $(".viewerSlider, .instructionMessaging, .desktopMessage").show();
    //Rotation sliders
    ReadyRotationSlider();
    ReadyZoomSlider();
    SetUpTimer();
} else if (isiPad || isAndroid || isiPhoneOriPod) {
    $('.viewerSlider').hide();
    $(".viewerSlider, .instructionMessaging, .mobileMessage").show();
    //alert('is an iPad, Android, or iPhone or iPod');
}
else {
    alert('is an something else');
    $('.viewerSlider').show();
}
//maybe get this to play
$('button').on("click", function () {
    image.trigger("play");
});


}); //End doc ready




function ZoomIn() {

// Zoom in Image but keep borders the same
var newWidth = $('.image').width() + zoomAmount;
var newHeight = $('.image').height() + zoomAmount;

//Move and zoom the image
var newX = (originalHeight - newHeight) / 2;
var newY = (originalWidth - newWidth) / 2;

$('.imgHolder').find('img').stop(false, true).animate({ 'width': newWidth, 'height': newHeight, 'top': newX, 'left': newY }, { duration: 200 });
}

function ZoomOut() {
// Zoom in Image but keep borders the same
var newWidth = $('.image').width() - zoomAmount;
var newHeight = $('.image').height() - zoomAmount;

if (newHeight <= originalHeight || newWidth <= originalWidth) {
    newHeight = originalHeight;
    newWidth = originalWidth;
}

var newX = (originalHeight - newHeight) / 2;
var newY = (originalWidth - newWidth) / 2;

$('.imgHolder').find('img').stop(false, true).animate({ 'width': newWidth, 'height':  newHeight, 'top': newX, 'left': newY }, { duration: 200 });
 }

 function DefaultSize() {
$('.imgHolder').find('img').stop(false, true).animate({ 'width': originalWidth,  'height': originalHeight, 'top': 0, 'left': 0 }, { duration: 200 });
 }

 function FreeZoom(amount) {

// Zoom in Image but keep borders the same
var newWidth = originalWidth * ((100 + amount) / 100);
var newHeight = originalHeight * ((100 + amount) / 100);

var newX = (originalHeight - newHeight) / 2;
var newY = (originalWidth - newWidth) / 2;

$('.imgHolder').find('img').stop(false, true).animate({ 'width': newWidth, 'height': newHeight, 'top': newX, 'left': newY }, { duration: 200 });
}

 //Rotation Sliders

 function SetUpTimer() {
setInterval('UpdateImageViaSliders()', 50);
 }

function UpdateImageViaSliders() {
if (isObjectRotatingViaSlider) {
    RotateViaSlider($('.rotationSlider').slider("value"));
} else if (isObjectZoomingViaSlider) {
    FreeZoom($('.zoomSlider').slider("value"));
}
 }

function ReadyRotationSlider() {
$(".rotationSlider").slider({
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        isObjectRotatingViaSlider = true;
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        isObjectRotatingViaSlider = false;
    }
});
}

function ReadyZoomSlider() {
$(".zoomSlider").slider({
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        isObjectZoomingViaSlider = true;
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        isObjectZoomingViaSlider = false;
    }
});
 }

 function RotateViaSlider(rotateNumber) {
var newFrame = Math.floor((rotateNumber * totalFrames) / 100);
$('.image').trigger('frameChange', newFrame);
 }
```

In the HTML I have two sets of these.

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="imgHolder">
            <img class="image" src="images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0001.png" height="448" width="360" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="instructionMessaging">
        <p class="mobileMessage">
            Swipe to spin image</p>
        <p class="desktopMessage">
            Click and drag left and right to spin image</p>
    </div>
    <div class="controlsWrapper">
        <!--<div id="ZoomIn">
                        Zoom In
                    </div>-->
        <a href="#" class="ZoomIn controlBtn">(+) Zoom In</a>
        <!--<div id="ZoomOut">
                        Zoom Out
                    </div>-->
        <a href="#" class="ZoomOut controlBtn">(-) Zoom Out</a> <a href="#" class="DefaultSize controlBtn">
            Default size</a>
        <div class="viewerSlider">
            <span>Rotate</span>
            <div class="rotationSlider">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="viewerSlider">
            <span>Zoom</span><div class="zoomSlider">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="imageSequence" name="imageSequence" value="images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0001.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0002.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0003.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0004.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0005.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0006.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0007.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0008.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0009.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0010.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0011.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0012.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0013.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0014.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0015.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0016.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0017.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0018.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0019.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0020.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0021.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0022.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0023.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0024.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0025.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0026.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0027.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0028.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0029.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0030.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0031.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0032.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0033.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0034.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0035.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0036.png,images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0037.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://sscce.org/

Comment: Fully sscce is perhaps a bit much to ask for every single question, but providing the code sample was the right thing to do; cheers for the update, Carlos.

Answer (score 1):

The controls are only doing what they're told:

```js
$('.element').doStuff();
// doStuff is just a fake generic function
```

The controls are finding ALL elements with the class "element" and applying changes to them.  In some cases the element is the control itself (ex. ALL controls with the class `.ZoomIn` do the same thing... and I mean the same EXACT thing; they act as duplicates of one another in terms of the event you're binding) and in some cases it's the target (ex. ALL images with the class `.image` are affected).

So to make it work on an individual basis, you will need to modify the code using some sort of way to distinguish between them. The easiest is to wrap each "set" of images and controls up in some sort of Div. The div doesn't even need to be unique, because we'll limit ourselves within.

A generic example might look like:

```
$('.someButton').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var theImage = $this.closest('.parentDiv').find('.image'); // parentDiv is the classname of the mini wrapper
  theImage.doStuff(); // will only affect the image(s) inside the mini wrapper
});
```

Fixing the whole plugin is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, but I hope this gives you an understanding of what's going wrong. Remember when you're looking at the source code that a selector like `$('.image')` will grab ALL nodes with that classname.